# How to pass a variable into json file

Tags: bash, aws

I am trying to pass a variable into a json file.

This is my script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for BucketName in `aws s3api list-buckets | jq '.Buckets[].Name' | sed 's/"//g'`;
do
if [ "$(aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket $BucketName --policy file://policy.json)" ]; then
echo "Passed"
elso
echo "Failed"
fi
done
```

In `file://policy.json` I need to pass a variable called `BucketName` in the for loop.

This is my json file:

```json
{
   "Sid":  ,
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::"'$BucketName'"/*",
   "Condition": {
       "Bool": {
           "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
       }
   }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot "pass a variable to a file". You'll have to modify the file's content yourself (unless the application itself has a mechanism for replacing those placeholders). A quick solution that comes to mind is having a `policy_template.json` and generating a new `policy.json` with `sed` in each iteration, replacing the placeholder with the actual value, although I'd generally try to avoid modifying structured data with text editing tools. However, as the question stands now, it is not quite clear to me what exactly you're asking.

Comment: In policy.json file there is a variable $BucketName, I'm listing the buckets and storing in a variable named BucketName. In the next command Im calling as $BucketName.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here, but you can pass arguments from the shell to jq using the `--arg` or `--argjson` command line arguments. See [Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)